# How do I access an instance of a class from an AVLTree?

Tags: c#, avl-tree

I have a Windows From Application in C# and I use an AVLTree and populate it with instances of a class `Country(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e, LinkedList<string> list)`. The Country class have few attributes and I need to access them after I populate the AVLTree. The tree has methods like `InsertItem(T item)`, `Delete(T item)`, `InOrder(ref string buffer)`, `PreOrder(ref string buffer)`, `PostOrder(ref string buffer)`, `Contains(T item)`, `Count()`, `Height()` and `RemoveItem(T item)`. The data to create an instance of the class is from an Excel file and I use `foreach` loop to read the lines from the file and after every line is read the instance is created and the `InsertItem(T item)` method is used to populate the tree. The `Country()` class overrides `ToString()` method so I am able to print out the names of the countries but I need to be able to remove or manually edit country information.
This is the Country class

```
namespace International_Trading_Data
{
    class Country : IComparable
    {
        string name;
        string gdpGrowth;
        string inflation;
        string tradeBalance;
        string hdiRanking;
        LinkedList<string> mainTradePartners;

        public Country(string name, string gdpGrowth, string inflation, string tradeBalance, string hdiRanking, LinkedList<string> mainTradePartners)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.gdpGrowth = gdpGrowth;
            this.inflation = inflation;
            this.tradeBalance = tradeBalance;
            this.hdiRanking = hdiRanking;
            this.mainTradePartners = mainTradePartners;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string GdpGrowth
        {
            get { return gdpGrowth; }
            set { gdpGrowth = value; }
        }

        public string Inflation
        {
            get { return inflation; }
            set { inflation = value; }
        }

        public string TradeBalance
        {
            get { return tradeBalance; }
            set { tradeBalance = value; }
        }

        public string HdiRanking
        {
            get { return hdiRanking; }
            set { hdiRanking = value; }
        }

        public LinkedList<string> MainTradePartners
        {
            get { return mainTradePartners; }
            set {  mainTradePartners = value; }
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Country temp = (Country)obj;
            return name.CompareTo(temp.name);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name+"\n";
        }

    }
}
```

Node class:

```
namespace International_Trading_Data
{
    class Node<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private T data;
        public Node<T> Left, Right;
        private int balanceFactor = 0;

        public Node(T item)
        {
            data = item;
            Left = null;
            Right = null;
        }
        public T Data
        {
            set { data = value; }
            get { return data; }
        }

        public int BalanceFactor
        {
            set { balanceFactor = value; }
            get { return balanceFactor; }
        }
    }
}
```

BinaryTree class:

```
namespace International_Trading_Data
{
    class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        protected Node<T> root;
        public BinaryTree()
        {
            root = null;
        }
        public BinaryTree(Node<T> node)
        {
            root = node;
        }

        public void InOrder(ref string buffer)
        {
            inOrder(root, ref buffer);
        }

        private void inOrder(Node<T> tree, ref string buffer)
        {
            if (tree != null)
            {
                inOrder(tree.Left, ref buffer);
                buffer += tree.Data.ToString();
                inOrder(tree.Right, ref buffer);
            }
        }

        public void PreOrder(ref string buffer)
        {
            preOrder(root, ref buffer);
        }

        private void preOrder(Node<T> tree, ref string buffer)
        {
            if (tree != null)
            {
                buffer += tree.Data.ToString();
                preOrder(tree.Left, ref buffer);
                preOrder(tree.Right, ref buffer);
            }
        }

        public void PostOrder(ref string buffer)
        {
            postOrder(root, ref buffer);
        }

        private void postOrder(Node<T> tree, ref string buffer)
        {
            if (tree != null)
            {
                postOrder(tree.Left, ref buffer);
                postOrder(tree.Right, ref buffer);
                buffer += tree.Data.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

BinarySearchTree class:

```
namespace International_Trading_Data
{
    class BSTree<T> : BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        int c = 0;
        public BSTree()
        {
            root = null;
        }

        public void InsertItem(T item)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref root);
        }

        private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
                tree = new Node<T>(item);
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Right);
        }

        public int Height()
        {
            return height(root);
        }

        protected int height(Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (root == null)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                if (tree != null)
                {
                    return 1 + Math.Max(height(tree.Left), height(tree.Right));
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return count(root, ref c);
        }

        private int count(Node<T> tree, ref int c)
        {
            if (tree == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count(tree.Left, ref c);
                count(tree.Right, ref c);
                c++;
                return c;
            }
        }

        public Boolean Contains(T item)
        {
            return contains(ref root, item);
        }

        private Boolean contains(ref Node<T> tree, T item)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
             else if (tree != null)
            {
                if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
                {
                    return contains(ref tree.Left, item);
                }
                else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
                {
                    return contains(ref tree.Right, item);
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveItem(T item)
        {
            removeItem(item, ref root);
        }

        private void removeItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The tree doesn't have items.");
            }
            if (tree != null)
            {
                if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
                {
                    removeItem(item, ref tree.Left);
                }
                if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
                {
                    removeItem(item, ref tree.Right);
                }
                if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) == 0)
                {
                    if (tree.Left == null)
                    {
                        tree = tree.Right;
                    }
                    else if (tree.Right == null)
                    {
                        tree = tree.Left;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        T newRoot = leastItem(tree.Right);
                        tree.Data = newRoot;
                        removeItem(newRoot, ref tree.Right);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private T leastItem(Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Left == null)
                return tree.Data;
            else
                return leastItem(tree.Left);
        }
    }
}
```

AVLTree class:

```
namespace International_Trading_Data
{
    class AVLTree<T> : BSTree<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        public new void InsertItem(T item)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref root);
        }

        private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
            {
                tree = new Node<T>(item);
            }
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
            {
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
            }
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
            {
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Right);
            }
            tree.BalanceFactor = height(tree.Left) - height(tree.Right);
            if (tree.BalanceFactor <= -2)
            {
                rotateLeft(ref tree);
            }
            if (tree.BalanceFactor >= 2)
            {
                rotateRight(ref tree);
            }
        }

        public new void RemoveItem(T item)
        {
            removeItem(item, ref root);
        }

        private void removeItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The tree doesn't have items.");
            }
            else if (tree != null)
            {
                if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
                {
                    removeItem(item, ref tree.Left);
                }
                if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
                {
                    removeItem(item, ref tree.Right);
                }
                if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) == 0)
                {
                    if (tree.Left == null)
                    {
                        tree = tree.Right;
                    }
                    else if (tree.Right == null)
                    {
                        tree = tree.Left;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        T newRoot = leastItem(tree.Right);
                        tree.Data = newRoot;
                        removeItem(newRoot, ref tree.Right);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (tree != null)
            {
                tree.BalanceFactor = height(tree.Left) - height(tree.Right);
                if (tree.BalanceFactor <= -2)
                {
                    rotateLeft(ref tree);
                }
                if (tree.BalanceFactor >= 2)
                {
                    rotateRight(ref tree);
                }
            }
        }

        private T leastItem(Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Left == null)
                return tree.Data;
            else
                return leastItem(tree.Left);
        }

        private void rotateLeft(ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Right != null)
            {
                if (tree.Right.BalanceFactor > 0)
                {
                    rotateRight(ref tree.Right);
                }
                Node<T> oldRoot = tree;
                Node<T> newRoot = oldRoot.Right;
                oldRoot.Right = newRoot.Left;
                newRoot.Left = oldRoot;
                tree = newRoot;
            }
        }

        private void rotateRight(ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Left != null)
            {
                if (tree.Left.BalanceFactor < 0)
                {
                    rotateLeft(ref tree.Left);
                }
                Node<T> oldRoot = tree;
                Node<T> newRoot = oldRoot.Left;
                oldRoot.Left = newRoot.Right;
                newRoot.Right = oldRoot;
                tree = newRoot;
            }
        }

            public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(); 
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    }
}
```

This is all I have. If I use the debugger I can see the AVLTree and all its nodes with the instances of the Country class.
At the end of the `foreach` loop I don't have any instance of the class, they are all stored in the tree. How do I access them and edit the information with the methods the tree have?
Any answer will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a `Lookup(Key)` method or similar on the tree class? Does it implement `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: No @Lee, No I don't have any other method or interface implemented. I tried to implement    `IEnumerable<T>` but I don't know how to implement                `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }` methods.

Comment: Are you also writing the AVL tree implementation? From your question it looks like you have a tree which only allows insertion and deletion but not retrieval.

Comment: Yes @Lee, I am writing the AVL tree. It inherits from `BinarySearchTree` which inherits from `BinaryTree`. The `BinaryTree` has `InOrder`, `PreOrder` and `PostOrder` methods, the `BinarySearchTree` has `InsertItem`, `Height`, `Count`, `Contains` which is boolean, return true if item in tree and `RemoveItem`. The `AVLTree` only overrides the `InsertItem` and `RemoveItem` methods.

Comment: Can you add the code for your tree classes to the question instead of the `Country` class? It sounds like you just need to implement `Lookup` (and possibly implement `IEnumerable<Node>`) on `BinarySearchTree`.